# How can SE stop multiple Ids?

Tags: discussion

There are some users who have more than one profile and it is recognizable by finding repeated subjects and same methods in writing even by me as a non English speaker. Which policies has SE provided to stop these users and suspend their IDs? By Ip it is very easy to find it but what about people who use of different systems and IPs? I think it would be better to suspend these users not some who ask questions which you do not like. You can easily close their topics not try to suspend them. It makes mistrust in new users and the other audiences about EL&U policies.

P.S: Multiple Ids mean one user who has several Ids in one forum by using different IPs. Surely having different account is not the matter of my question as all users in this forum have many other accounts in the other forums of SE.

Comment: I'm really not sure we can (as mods) say anything besides "we have ways"

Comment: Can you provide some specifics?

Comment: @KitFox I cannot be sure about my examples so I think by this I will make enemies for myself! But I thought you may be able to find a way to stop them and recognize them by evidence.

Comment: Yes, we already do that. If you suspect that two users are the same, you can use the custom flag to bring it to our attention.

Comment: So it seems me and you are using same methods! :0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple IDs are permitted. But the use of multiple IDs for fraud, such as vote stuffing, is not permitted and should be flagged.

Comment: Multiple IDs aren't allowed if they are used to circumvent a suspension, either.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That counts as fraud.