# What are these weird symbols that keep showing up in certain posts?

Tags: discussion

For example:

---==,--=.-.,=-==-----

What does that mean? I have seen that and its ilk in a few posts by new users. Is that a, you know, *thing* now?

And, I hesitate to ask--feel free to ignore--but who or what is Nortonn S?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Nortonn S](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/23135/nortonn-s) is a suspended user.

The random punctuation is a trademark of his which he adds to sockpuppet posts. It's a reliable signpost and is helping my [flag count](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3818/how-can-se-stop-multiple-ids) — and probably that of others.

All of these "new users" are one person.

Comment: Thanks. What a villain! A Zorro flourish and everything.

Comment: How come no-one blocks the IP he is using to post in your name?

Comment: @mplungjan You may well ask! But I suspect that it's a dynamic IP address.

Comment: As for what it *means*, it looks a bit like an ASCII alligator.

Comment: @MετάEd  It bears a passing resemblence to [Geek Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geek_Code) too, but I'm pretty sure that's not it.